# If your models are persistence agnostic, how do you save them?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, language-agnostic, persistence-ignorance

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC, coming from a PHP MVC background. It's been kind of an awkward transition (see my question history, heh.)

One thing I like a lot in theory that's big in the .Net world is the idea of models being persistence agnostic. But in this case, what is the proper way to save changes to a model? In PHP, I'd just call `$model->save();` after doing some transformation. In C#, I'm not sure of how to do that.

Is this appropriate?

```
public class AwesomesauceController
{
    //inject!
    public AwesomeSauceController(IDataAccess da)
    {
        DataAccess = da;    
    }
    private readonly IDataAccess DataAccess;

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int Id)
    {
        // PHP equiv: AwesomeSauceModel::find($id); Controller is unaware of DAL
        return View(DataAccess.AwesomeSauces.Where( sc => sc.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(AwesomeSauce sc)
    {
        //persistence-aware version: model is aware of DAL, but controller is not
         if($sc->valid()
            $sc->save(); 
            redirect(); 
        }
        else { return view(); }

        // compare to persistence-agnostic version, controller is aware of DAL, but model is not
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            da.Persist(sc);
            return Redirect();
        }
        else
        {
            return View(sc);
        }
    }
}
```

I guess the only thing that strikes me as wrong about this is that typically, I wouldn't want a controller to be directly accessing a data access layer in this way. Previously, in PHP land, my controllers would access models and views only, basically.

Comment: From `$model->save();` I deduce that you're probably used to an [active record pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html). Compare that with the [repository pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html). Sure your PHP controllers only access models and views, but, as is common in [active record][1], your models have data access logic in them (that `save()` method!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is fine.  ActiveRecord vs Repository vs Home Brew DAL is an eternal question that we'll discuss forever.

The [repository pattern](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=repository+pattern) is very popular in the .NET world right now and you'll probably see a lot of examples of its usage.  MVC doesn't care what your data access strategy is though.  Using whatever you find comfortable is just fine and a better strategy than using a pattern because everybody else is doing it.

Answer (score 1):

It's OK for a model to have a Save() function, but you would usually want that Save() behavior to be independent of your model -- abstracted away to an interface.

Remember your design principles: design to an interface, not an implementation.

Another caveat is how do you test your pieces individually?  If a model doesn't know how it's persisted, it can be tested based on what a model *should* do, and your persistence mechanism can be tested based on what it *should* do.

In any case, it looks like your Create() action is doing double duty -- trying to use the model to Save, then trying to use the DataAccess to persist.  Are these two objects doing the same thing?  Could this be confusing or unreadable/unmaintainable later on?

Comment: The create action (which should actually be called `Edit`) has both a persistence-agnostic version (the latter) and a persistence-aware version (the former), for comparison purposes. -- I tried to clarify this in the original question.